# The 'real-time' search isn't supported because of the infinite Splunk Job nature

Tags: spring, splunk

I am getting the following error when executing the real time search via Spring Splunk inbound adapter.

```
SEVERE: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: search Splunk data failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The 'real-time' search isn't supported because of the infinite Splunk Job nature.
```

Can anybody let me know how to execute real-time search from Spring application?

Comment: How are you trying to do this now? Can you show some of your code?

Comment: I am doing what is mentioning here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-extensions/tree/master/spring-integration-splunk Have you successfully ran it?

Comment: What XML config are you using? This is the example config for a realtime search: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-splunk#realtime-search

Comment: Ok. Apart from SplunkInboundChannelAdapterCommon-context.xml and SplunkCommon-context.xml, I am using an XML where I have mentioned the search command. Following is the content of it.

<int-splunk:inbound-channel-adapter id="splunkInboundChannelAdapter"
auto-startup="true" search="sourcetype=SplunkRabbitMQ_messaging | spath input=msg_body | where '3' > 0" splunk-server-ref="splunkServer" channel="inputFromSplunk" mode="NORMAL" earliest-time="-5s" latest-time="rt" init-earliest-time="-1d">
<int:poller fixed-rate="5" time-unit="SECONDS"/>
</int-splunk:inbound-channel-adapter>

Comment: Command is working fine when i used in the GUI

Comment: I used mode = REALTIME not NORMAL

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the mode in your XML config:

```
mode="REALTIME"
```

Comment: After setting it REALTIME it is showing the line mentioned in the question above. If you see the source code of the adapter, it is hardcoded in it to print it like this.

Comment: I need to know why it is hardcoded like this and is their any work around of it?

Comment: In that case, create an issue on their GitHub repository asking for this this feature to be supported: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-splunk/issues

Their code is using using the Splunk SDK for Java to communicate with Splunk, and we have some guidance on how to work with real-time searches here: http://dev.splunk.com/view/java-sdk/SP-CAAAEHQ#realtimejob You may be able to make some changes to spring-integration-splunk and send them a pull request on GitHub.

Comment: I guess its not supported yet. What do you think? https://jira.spring.io/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/INTEXT-72

Comment: I don't know enough about the architecture of spring, but there needs to be a "polling" process to check for new events at some interval for realtime searches.

Comment: but that can happen with any other search like mode=NORMAL right?